# javac NotRecognized - Java version 1.8.0_161 |

Tags: java, javac

I'm testing out some code on a computer running Windows 8.1.

I'm using the command prompt and I can't seem to get javac (or javaC) to compile my text file. I've added the path as an environment variable (...\bin) and it doesn't do work. `java -version` and `java` prints information to the console, just can't get javac to work.

Comment: could you please add more details here like which java, echo $PATH, lsb_release -a, etc

Comment: Are you sure you installed JDK? May be you have installed JRE only and `javac` does not come with JRE.

Comment: Have you [Googled](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/download_options.xml#windows) any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are having JRE installed on your machine. You can go to your JAVA_HOME/bin folder, check if javac file is there or not. If not, it means you have JRE installed. You need to install java JDK.

FOr download jdk, this is the url for JDK 8:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Previous version available here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html

Comment: it appears you are right. somehow i seem to have downloaded the wrong file the first time. I appreciate it.

Comment: Great. If my answer helped you in resolving your issue, then please upvote/mark it as useful :) Thank you

Comment: do you know how i can get an old version of JDK? Java SE 9 isnt compatable with the computer

Comment: This is the url: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html